# How to switch functions javascript

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

I'd like to make something small. When you enter Celsius, the program should calculate Fahrenheit and vice-versa. But when I enter the celsius and click the button it does the vice-versa aswell. Since I'm a beginner I don't really know how not to execute function2 if function1 activates. My javascript looks like this:

JS:

```js
function Omrekenen() {
  var celsius = document.getElementById('Celsius').value;
  var fahrenheit = document.getElementById('Fahrenheit').value;


  var r1 = (celsius * 1.8) + 32;
  var r2 = (fahrenheit / 1.8) - 32;
}

function Leeg1() {
  document.getElementById('Fahrenheit').value = "";
}

function Leeg2() {
  document.getElementById('Celsius').value = "";
}
```

```html
<div class="Oefening">
  <h1 class="Titel">Oefening 3</h1>
  Celsius: <input type="number" id="Celsius" placeholder="°C" onkeyup=Leeg1()> Fahrenheit: <input type="number" id="Fahrenheit" placeholder="°F" onkeyup="Leeg2()"><br />
  <input type="button" id="button3" value="Zet om" onclick="Omrekenen(); Vast();" class="Button">
</div>
```

Comment: Use an `if` statement to check to see which input has a value, or which is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing this.

Note that I'm checking for the length of the value from the input. You can't check the truthiness (`if (celsius) ...`) in this case, since a value of `0` is valid, but would evaluate to false. Checking the length should work for each case.

```js
function Omrekenen() {
  var celsius = document.getElementById('Celsius').value;
  var fahrenheit = document.getElementById('Fahrenheit').value;

  if (celsius.length !== 0) {
      document.getElementById('Fahrenheit').value = (celsius * 1.8) + 32;      
  } else if (fahrenheit.length !== 0) {
      document.getElementById('Celsius').value = (fahrenheit / 1.8) - 32;          
  }
  
}

function Leeg1() {
  document.getElementById('Fahrenheit').value = "";
}

function Leeg2() {
  document.getElementById('Celsius').value = "";
}
```

```html
<div class="Oefening">
  <h1 class="Titel">Oefening 3</h1>
  Celsius: <input type="number" id="Celsius" placeholder="°C" onkeyup=Leeg1()> Fahrenheit: <input type="number" id="Fahrenheit" placeholder="°F" onkeyup="Leeg2()"><br />
  <input type="button" id="button3" value="Zet om" onclick="Omrekenen();" class="Button">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state variable also, but you'd also want to handle the paste action in that case.

```
<script>
var isCalculatingCelsius;
function Omrekenen()
{

  var celsius = document.getElementById('Celsius').value;
  var  fahrenheit = document.getElementById('Fahrenheit').value;


  if (isCalculatingCelsius){ 
    document.getElementById('Celsius').value = (fahrenheit / 1.8) - 32;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('Fahrenheit').value = (celsius * 1.8) + 32;
  }
}

function Leeg1(){
  isCalculatingCelsius = false;
  document.getElementById('Fahrenheit').value = "";
}

function Leeg2(){
  isCalculatingCelsius = true;
  document.getElementById('Celsius').value = "";
}

</script>
<div class="Oefening">
  <h1 class="Titel">Oefening 3</h1>
  Celsius: <input type="number" id="Celsius" placeholder="°C" onkeyup="Leeg1()">
  Fahrenheit: <input type="number" id="Fahrenheit" placeholder="°F" onkeyup="Leeg2()"><br />
  <input type="button" id="button3" value="Zet om" onclick="Omrekenen()" class="Button">
</div>
```